# Can I add https url as my seed with Crawler4j

Tags: web-crawler, crawler4j

I have to crawl through an ssl website using crawler4j-4.1.jar and its dependencies. Can I add an https url as my first seed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Crawler4j supports ssl authenticated sites also.